# MYSQL trying to get other attributes from max value

Tags: mysql, attributes, max

I have this trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_bid_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON Bids
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN


IF NEW.amount > (SELECT B.amount, B.vin FROM Bids B WHERE B.vin = NEW.vin AND B.amount = (SELECT MAX(amount) from Bids))  THEN
INSERT INTO Notifications (buyer, outbidded, vin, amount) values (NEW.buyer, B.buyer, NEW.vin, NEW.amount);


END IF ;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

With tables

```
CREATE TABLE Auctions
(seller VARCHAR(100),
vin VARCHAR(20),
brand VARCHAR(20),
cartype VARCHAR(20),
model VARCHAR(20),
color VARCHAR(20),
minprice int,
dt DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY (vin, seller)
);

CREATE TABLE Bids
(buyer VARCHAR(20),
vin VARCHAR(20),
amount int,
autobid int,
upperlimit int,
PRIMARY KEY(buyer, vin, amount),
FOREIGN KEY (vin) REFERENCES Auctions(vin)

);

CREATE TABLE Notifications
(buyer VARCHAR(20),
outbidded VARCHAR(20),
vin VARCHAR(20),
amount int,
PRIMARY KEY(vin, buyer),
FOREIGN KEY (vin) REFERENCES Bids(vin),
FOREIGN KEY (buyer) REFERENCES Bids(buyer)
);
```

However whenever I run it, it says operand should contain 1 columns.

What i'm trying to do is, if the row thats being inserted has a higher amount value than any row already in the bids table with the same VIN as the new row, then insert the values into notifications.

Comment: `NEW.amount > (SELECT B.amount, B.vin... ` You are comparing amount to 2 columns? Try to remove `B.vin` from the select.

Comment: I got this error "Unknown column 'B.buyer' in 'field list' "

Comment: my bids table looks like this                                                     
  CREATE TABLE Bids
 (buyer VARCHAR(20),
 vin VARCHAR(20),
 amount int,
 autobid int,
 upperlimit int,
 PRIMARY KEY(buyer, vin, amount),
 FOREIGN KEY (vin) REFERENCES Auctions(vin)

Comment: That's a different error now with the next line. `INSERT INTO Notifications (buyer, outbidded, vin, amount) values (NEW.buyer, B.buyer, NEW.vin, NEW.amount);` Shouldn't that be `NEW.outbidded` instead of `B.buyer`?

Comment: Update the question with more details such as the Create table and other things instead of posting in comments.

Comment: I want the name of the buyer who held the previous highest amount (which i think would be "b.buyer" however it says its unknown

Comment: What is `B` here? You need to select the value from a table here. Cannot use aliases used in the previous select.

Comment: Is there a way that I can make the B.buyer from the previous select into some sort of variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to help with both your issues:

```
SELECT B.amount INTO @amount, B.buyer INTO @buyer 
    FROM Bids B WHERE B.vin = NEW.vin AND B.amount = (SELECT MAX(amount) from Bids)

IF NEW.amount > @amount  THEN
INSERT INTO Notifications (buyer, outbidded, vin, amount)
values (NEW.buyer, @buyer, NEW.vin, NEW.amount);
```

Also, not sure but I feel you should have another check in `SELECT MAX(amount) from Bids` query to include a `WHERE` clause to check for `vin`.